# Is there any significant Geometric/analytic property of the Pearson coefficent that could be applied to statistics?

Tags: geometry, analysis, statistics, big-list

Is there many significant Geometric/analytic property that the Pearson coefficent has which could be applied to statistics?

It seems very interesting to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pearson product moment correlation is the cosine of the angle between the two regression lines (y regressed on x and x regressed on y).  For perfect correlation r=1 or r=-1 the two lines coincide.  when the correlation is zero the lines are perpendicular to each other.  [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) is a link to a wikipedia article describing the geometry.

Answer (score 0):

If the correlation between $x$ and $y$ is $0.9$ and that between $y$ and $z$ is $0.9$, what's the smallest the correlation between $x$ and $z$ could be?  Just remember that the correlation is the cosine of an angle, and ask how big a certain angle could be.